# gitで複数のファイルを一括で移動またはリネームする方法を教えてください

Tags: git

gitリポジトリ内の全erbファイルをhamlにリネームしたいです。（例: index.html.erb => index.html.haml）

以下のようなコマンドで一つずつリネームするのは大変です。

```
$ git mv app/views/pages/index.html.erb app/views/pages/index.html.haml
```

また、こんなコマンドが使えるかなと思ったのですが、無理でした。

```
$ git mv app/views/**/*.erb app/views/**/*.haml

usage: git mv [options] <source>... <destination>

    -n, --dry-run         dry run
    -f, --force           force move/rename even if target exists
    -k                    skip move/rename errors
```

こういう場合はどうすればよいでしょうか？

Comment: 注：この質問は過去に英語版に投稿した質問を転記したものです。 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151920/git-rename-or-move-all-files-at-once

Answer (score 13, accepted):

質問者と同じく[英語版サイトの解答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9151943/4037)を入れると

```
for i in $(find . -iname "*.erb"); do
    git mv "$i" "$(echo $i | rev | cut -d '.' -f 2- | rev).haml";
done
```

ですが、これだけだと価値を足していないので、解説してみます。

```
$(find . -iname "*.erb")
```

で、`.erb` で終わるファイルをすべてリストアップします。それを `for` で1つずつ見ていきます。

次に

```
$(echo $i | rev | cut -d '.' -f 2- | rev)
```

を見ていきます。

```
echo $i | rev
```

でファイルへのパスを逆向きにします（例：`app/views/person/index.html.erb` -> `bre.xedni/nosrep/sweiv/ppa`）。

```
cut -d '.' -f 2-
```

で、ファイルをドット `.` で区切り、2番目以降だけ取り出します（つまり、`bre.` だけ消す）。

最後に `rev` で文字を元の正方向に戻します。（例：`xedni/nosrep/sweiv/ppa` -> `app/views/person/index`）

これで

```
git mv "$i" "$(echo $i | rev | cut -d '.' -f 2- | rev).haml";
```

は元のファイル名から `.erb` だけ削り、`.haml` を加えて、`git mv` に渡すって感じになります。

Comment: Bash の文字列置換（この場合後方一致の削除）を使った `${i%.edb}.haml` というのはどうでしょうか？

Comment: @yosh なるほど、いいですねー。本家SOの答えは他のシェルでも使えるようにしてるのかもしれません。

Answer (score 7):

(私のように) `for` 文のどこにセミコロンを入れたらいいか覚えられない場合は xargs が使えます。

```
find . -iname "*.erb" -not -path './vendor/*' \
  | rev | cut -d. -f2- | rev | xargs -IF git mv F.erb F.haml
```

実行前に何が起こるか確認するには、最後に -n 引数を入れるか、echo を git mv の前に入れます。

```
find . -iname "*.erb" -not -path './vendor/*' \
  | rev | cut -d. -f2- | rev | xargs -IF echo git mv F.erb F.haml
```

Answer (score 5):

こういう明らかに ruby がインストールされている環境では、 ruby を使うと簡単だと思います。

```
% ruby -e 'Dir.glob("app/views/**/*.erb") { |n| `git mv #{n} #{n.gsub(/erb$/,"haml")}` }'
```

Answer (score 4):

おそらくやりたいことは、単なるリネームでは無くてERBからHAMLへの移行だと思います。

[erb2haml](https://github.com/dhl/erb2haml) を導入した後、

```
rake haml:replace_erbs
git add --all
```

とすると、ERBからHAMLに変換した後、レポジトリから *.erb を削除、*.haml を追加することができます。

Answer (score 2):

自分の経験からなんですが、ファイル名変更のみの作業で `git mv` は必要ありません。というのは git は、パスやファイル名からではなく、ファイルの中身で、ファイルの位置を認識・検知するからです。
ですから、「*ファイルの中身を大きく変更せずに、拡張子だけを変更したような場合*」には、普通にしていれば、まあ、大抵は、「**ファイル名を変更したと自動検知**」されます。

ですので、この質問への答えは、「気軽にファイル名を変更して、`git add . -A` する」かな。

具体的な方法ですが、ファイル名の変更自体はどんなやりかたでもよく、例えば:

```
find app/views -name "*.erb" -exec rename .erb .haml \{\} \;
```

もしくはシステムによっては:

```
find app/views -name "*.erb" -exec rename 's/.erb$/.haml/g' \{\} \;
```

として作業を終えた後:

```
git add . -A
git status
```

とします。名前変更されたファイルは、renamed として認識されるはずです。 (`-A` オプションで add/rm を同時に行なわせるのが重要です ) ファイルの変更があまり大きくない場合は、これで事足りるでしょう。

**補足**: サブディレクトリを対象にせず、そのディレクトリのファイルの名前を変更するだけならば、

```
rename .erb .haml *.erb
git add . -A
```

もしくは、

```
rename 's/.erb/.haml/g' *.erb
git add . -A
```

で済みます。